# Como poner videos de youtube en aplicacion Android

Tags: android-studio, cardview

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion donde quiero mostrar videos de youtube en un fragmento que tiene CardsViews, mis cardviews ya funcionan sin problema, el problema es que no se reproducen los videos, siempre meda un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los videos los estoy agregando en un WebView y los link de los videos los uso de la siguiente forma: **http://www.youtube.com/embed/\"+yS_p_ICLUAw+\"?autoplay=1&vq=small**

La configuración del WebView es la siguiente:

```
holder.reproductor.loadUrl(tips.getEnlace());
        holder.reproductor.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        holder.reproductor.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
        holder.reproductor.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
            }
        });
```

Este es el error que muestra con la URL que pongo en el WebView:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que error te muestra Enrique? , es importante agregar el mensaje que se muestra para saber como aportar una solución.

Comment: @Jorgesys ya actualice la pregunta, realmente no me muestra un error al momento de ejecutar el fragmento con los cardview y el webview, el error es que cualquier Id que pongo en el lin de youtube no me los reproduce, me muestra el error que coloque en la parte final de la pregunta

Comment: Asi es como tengo la URL que le paso al webview:
http://www.youtube.com/embed/\"+yS_p_ICLUAw+\"?autoplay=1&vq=small

Comment: Te encuentras escapando caracteres, por lo tanto la url es invalida, @EnriqueEspinosa agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a la definición de la url del video, esto es incorrecto ya que define una url incorrecta,

> "http://youtube.com/embed\"+yS_p_ICLUAw+\"?autoplay=1&vq=small ";

**la url no debe hacer uso de "`\`" ya que estarías escapando algunos caracteres ( `\"` )** , esto es la correcta definición de la url del video youtube:

> "http://www.youtube.com/embed/yS_p_ICLUAw?autoplay=1&vq=small"

, revisa este ejemplo:

```
 String urlVideo = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/yS_p_ICLUAw?autoplay=1&vq=small";
 webView.loadUrl(urlVideo);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Como comentario: te aconsejo amplia mente el uso de [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Este es un ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Youtube-API

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes razon, no me percate de como estaba concatenando la url, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, revisare el API que me comentas.

Answer (score 0):

en lugar de usar un webview te recomiendo que utilices un MediaPlayer y le pases la url del video, algo asi:

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp.setDataSource(url);
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
```

Ademas si lo vas a usar en un adapter trata de tener solo 1 MediaPlayer y no uno por cada card o podria causarte problemas.

Comment: Hola Erick, ya intente usar un VideoView pero cuando pasa la URL me dice que no puede reproducir el video, de echo converti la URL en URI pero me sigue marcando el mismo error por eso estoy usando un webview